# Pop up created by CFUserNotificationCreate is not coming to front

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsusernotification

This is bit tricky situation. I want to display a dialogue to the user from daemon, that dialog should come in front of all other open windows on screen. In regular cases CFUserNotificationCreate just working fine. But say open xcode from that try to open a file by using the "open window", if for some reason that window is hung, dialogue from  CFUserNotificationCreate is not coming on top of such windows. Is there any solution for that/ Is there any way to display dialogue other than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consulting with Apple, got to know this is a bug which exists with few applications. We had raised Apple bug ticket for the enhancement.